# Using React Context with Next 14

Tags: caching, next.js, react-context, react-server-components

I have a site with articles that can be bookmarked, saved to a database when the bookmark icon is clicked. If I revisit an article that I've already bookmarked, the bookmarked icon should be disabled (page will see the article id is bookmarked already via React Context).

I am playing around with upgrading the site with Next 14.  Should I still be using React Context for this functionality?  I'm wondering if Next's data caching would be an option but so far, I'm not having any luck.  The db query seems to fire on every page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"In Next.js 14, including `use client` at the beginning of your component file is essential if you plan to leverage React Context. This addresses your question regarding the continued use of context.

Regarding caching, the Next.js documentation (https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/caching) clarifies that caching effectiveness depends on how you structure your APIs. It's worth noting that caching database data might not significantly enhance user experience (UX). I think the documentation emphasizes caching for HTML, CSS, and other non-data elements rather than the actual database information."

Comment: Thank you.  I ended up using Context and calling some server actions from there to make changes to the db.